# How to re-order worksheets using python's xslxwriter

Tags: excel, python-3.4

I am using xslxwriter to produce a excel spreadsheet, and I am wondering if there is anyway I can  re-order my worksheets in my workbook.

I have tried to change the index, but this doesn't seem to work (index doesn't seem to alter the order).

Any idea if this can be done with xslxwriter, or is there another module I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, unfortunately not in the xslxwriter module but the pywin32 addin.

Using the following you can reorder your sheet "WorkSheetToMove" in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename="excelyouwanttoreoder.xslx", ReadOnly='False')
for worksheet in wb.Sheets:
    if worksheet.Name == "WorkSheetToMove":
           worksheet.Move(Before=wb.Sheets("Sheet2"))
wb.Close()
```